# Use cached pages with Ratchet (Push.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ratchet-bootstrap, push.js

I'm developing an hybrid app and I'm using [Ratchet](http://goratchet.com) for that. On the first page (index.html) the app retrieves content dynamically and adds that content via jQuery to the DOM. When I navigate to another tab (sub-page), and navigate back to the main page (index.html), everything is gone.

How can I navigate (or use) the cached page of the main page?

Answer (score 0):

Ratchet relies upon an MPA (multiple page architecture) while you need a SPA (single p.a.): you can change your framework OR have a workaround (i.e.: you can first cache data in a JSON using localStorage and then retrieve them in the showing pages).

P.S.: I warmly suggest you to rely on a SPA-oriented framework, to keep it simple and efficient.